# want change selected powerpoint chart series color in vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Dim p As Point
Dim s As Series
Dim c As Chart

Set c = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart
Set s = c.SeriesCollection(1)

With s
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(25, 26, 24)
End With    

End Sub
```

Comment: We need more of a description of what works and what doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51792654/edit) to include more information.  What does your current code do, and what to you want to do instead?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax seems to be correct.  You simply need to make sure that you select your chart before running the macro.  Otherwise, you'll get a run-time error "Selection (unknown member): Invalid request.  Nothing appropriate is currently selected."

Comment: There is no "ActiveChart" in powerpoint.

Comment: @RobertMuehsig You're absolutely correct.  As a result, I have edited my post.  I may have missed the fact that the code is running in PowerPoint.  In any case, thanks for pointing it out.  I really appreciate it.  Cheers!